# Mingw cannot find any sfml libraries

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, sfml

I was trying to set up Sfml for my c ++ project by watching tutorials and documentation on how to do this.
I am using Mingw to compile and produce an executable, see how it goes.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Mingw command line input

```
g++ mycppfile -o myexefile -IDependencies/include -LDependencies/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32
```

But this error always appears.

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-graphics
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-window
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-system
```

I've researched many times trying to solve this problem, reviewed the names of the libraries, put all the Sfml dependencies in my project folder and the compiler folder, and also put the Sfml Dlls in the system32 folder and my project folder, but the problem has not yet been solved.

What can I do now?

Comment: Research the `-I` (upper case I) and `-L` (upper case l) options for your compiler.

Comment: Please demonstrate which library files you put into which folder and from where and with what command line exactly you are invoking the compiler.

Comment: @walnut The code used to compile is this:
`g++ mycppfile -o myexefile -IDependencies/include -LDependencies/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32`
The libraries are in my project folder in the Dependencies/lib folder.

Comment: @Davindodeumlugar What exactly is in `Dependencies/lib`? The compiler does not search for the library file (i.e. `libsfml-system.a`/`libsfml-system.so`/`libsfml-system.lib` or similar) recursively. It will only look in `Dependencies/lib` itself.

Comment: @walnut Now I realized what the problem was, when I put the Sfml Dlls in the Dependencies/lib folder it worked, thanks for telling me that the problem was not in the libraries. I now had a rendering problem, but that's another matter.